# How does hadoop enforce that jobs don't share CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hadoop2, emr, amazon-emr

When hadoop allocates a vcore to a particular container, how does it make sure that other containers do not use that cpu? Does the container have exclusive access to the cpu or other containers can share the cpu if the cpu in question has free cycles.

Am asking because in almost all of the AWS nodes, the memory is 4x the number of vCPUs. For example in case of m4.large which has 2CPUs and 8GB memory, if we set the container size to 2GB, then we get 4 containers. But since we only have 2CPUs, how are the 2 CPUs divided between the 4 containers?